# Total com pluralize em template Django

Tags: django, template

Pessoal eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div>
    <h4>{{ combination|length }} combinação{{ combination|length|pluralize }}</h4>
    <h5><b>Total:</b> {{ combination.paginator.count }} combinação{{ combination.paginator.count|pluralize }}</h5>
</div>
```

Ele me retorna a quantidade de combinações. Quer dizer, no plural ele está fazendo combinaçãos.
Como corrigir isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação o pluralize aceita o argumento no singular e plural.

```
<h4>
{{ combination|length }} 
combina{{ combination|length|pluralize:"ção,ções" }}
</h4>
```

ele vai mostrar:

```
0 combinações
1 combinação
2 combinações
```

Comment: Obrigado. Principalmente pela educação.

Comment: Opa! É um prazer ajudar. Esqueci de postar o link da documentação  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize